# Image upload to SSL folder, status code 200, headers {connection = closed}

Tags: php, ios, ssl

I'm trying to connect to the php file in my SSL folder on my server to upload images taken within my app, all certificates etc are in place and the dir has permissions set to 777 but I'm getting an error code 200 and no uploaded image.

The section of code within my ViewController.m related to this is

```
- (IBAction)subirImagen:(id)sender {
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imagen.image);

    NSString *urlString = @"https://secure101.prositehosting.co.uk/php-upload-file-server-master2/subir.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];




    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body initMultipart];
    [body addPart:@"myFile" withFileName:@"imagen.png" withNSData:imageData];
    [body addPart:@"myName" withValue:@"Ricardo"];
    [body writeLastBoundary];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSError* err = nil;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPURLResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSInteger statusCode = [HTTPURLResponse statusCode];

    NSString* mensaje = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Request: %ld",(long)statusCode];
    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server"
                                                          message:mensaje
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [myAlertView show];

    NSLog(@"Response Meta: %@", response);
    NSLog(@"String sent from server %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    //As was advised
    NSHTTPURLResponse* newResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    //crash here
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)newResp.statusCode);

}
```

The php file is

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
//header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

if (isset($_POST['comentario']) && isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if (isset($_FILES['myFile'])) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'], "./" . $_FILES['myFile']['name']);
    }


    $respuesta = array("code"=>2000,"message"=>"successful", "comentario"=>$comentario, "id"=>$id);
    // $class_response = json_decode(json_encode($respuesta));
    // echo $class_response->comentario;
    //echo $comentario;
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
}
else{
    $respuesta = array("code"=>4000,"message"=>"fail");
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
}



?>
```

The error response is

```
   <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1545b4360> { URL: https://secure101.prositehosting.co.uk/php-upload-file-server-master2/subir.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 17 Jun 2015 10:55:46 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} }
2015-06-17 11:55:55.556 CameraApp[1647:643453] String sent from server {"code":4000,"message":"fail"}
```

I have implemented the TLS keys in Xcode in the info.plist file to go with the new standards announced for iOS 9 but still no luck uploading any image.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 200 is the HTTP status code for "OK". It is returned when a request is handled successfully.

Since you are receiving the JSON response

```
{"code":4000,"message":"fail"}
```

one can infer that the conditional statement

```
if (isset($_POST['comentario']) && isset($_POST['id']))
```

is returning false.

No surprise there, as you're not sending the fields `commentario` and `id` in your `POST` request.

You will have to include those fields or make modifications to the server side php code.

You might also want to return another HTTP status code when the error response is sent because of the missing fields. I suggest 400 for "Bad request".